# How to get Store Name by using Multiple Store Id in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get store name by using multiple store ids in magento. like:

```
<?php $store_ids= array(1,2,3);
```

Now how to get store names of these store ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way I can think is:

```
Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
```

So use :

```
$store_ids= array(1,2,3);
foreach($store_ids as $storeId){
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
$name = $store->getName();
}
```

That's what else you can have from object $store:

```
        [code] => 
        [website_id] => 
        [group_id] => 
        [name] => 
        [sort_order] => 
        [is_active] =>
```

Comment: Thankyou vbak. its working for me.

Comment: @vbak How can we do the same in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

> $store_ids= array(1,2,3);
>   $stores=Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
>   ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('in'=>$store_ids))->addFieldToSelect('name');
>
> ```
> foreach( $stores as $eachStore){
>
> echo $eachStore->getName();
>
> }
> ```

As you want to   `only store name of multiple stores`  that why i am suggest to use `store collection and  filter them by store_id` `instead of use store model(Mage::getModel('core/store')) and load them one by one.`

It is better for coding.

- **In magento,you can get store collection by below code:**

`Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()`

- **Now you nee filter the collection by store_id and with in array
  conditions:**